# Path to VersionInfo.plist from app bundle

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I am currently working on CoreData, but I am getting some errors. I have tried all the solutions stated on StackOverflow, except for one:

Make sure the NSManagedObjectModel_CurrentVersionName is correct.

There are posts of people suggesting going to app bundle -> coreData.momd -> VersionInfo.plist to do the checking.

However, I cannot even find where my app bundle is. I can find my build folder with intermediates and products. However, nothing in those folders direct me to the app bundle.

Any help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the currently selected version by selecting the .cxdatamodeld file in the Project Navigator pane on the left of the screen.  Then, in the Utilities pane on the right of the screen select the File Inspector and under Versioned Core Data Model is the selection for "Current".  This should show your current data model.

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and type the following command:

> find / -name "VersionInfo.plist"

Mine is in "./Users/blossomwoo/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/DB103D5D-9FFA-4E95-9715-944E8E339FCB/.app/DataModel.momd/"